# Get font file from font family

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, pygame

Having a difficult time trying to get the proper .ttf file from the font family.

Currently trying to use pygame to work on some graphics and it has its own internal search function to find a font file from the Font Family but it's not correct.

Also tried using matplotlib.font_manager. This also is not correct.

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
import pygame

pygame.font.init()

print(font_manager.findfont('Segoe UI'))
    > C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\seguisb.ttf
print(pygame.font.match_font('Segoe UI'))
    > C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\segoeuil.ttf
print(font_manager.findfont('Arial'))
    > C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\arial.ttf
print(pygame.font.match_font('Arial'))
    > C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\ARIALN.TTF
```

I'm hoping there's something I missed and there is a way to get a complete match on the search, not a partial match (I'm guessing both methods used are reading the byte array and returning the closest matching font based on the Family. I.e., 'Segoe UI' is in 'Segoe UI Bold' so it was returned as the match).

Comment: unless you have a comparing list of exact font names it will not work as you expect, I guess its working as a like query in databases, one approach is, you can filter the retrieved font names by removing words like 'bold', 'regular', 'light', 'thin' etc which are typically present in font names. and then remove any duplicate names. That may give you the decent list of font names.

Comment: Hmmm the .findfont() and .match_font() don't return a list of fonts that match it though, just the closest one. I think I'm going to have to end up reading the ttf file and find the one that == the font name supplied. Windows display the font name in the Fonts folder, not the font file name, correctly. And it display the font name in the tooltip when you hover over a font.ttf file. So I'm sure there's a way to read the font file.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [`pygame.font.SysFont()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont):

> Return a new Font object that is loaded from the system fonts. The font will match the requested bold and italic flags. **Pygame uses a small set of common font aliases**. If the specific font you ask for is not available, a reasonable alternative may be used. If a suitable system font is not found this will fall back on loading the default pygame font.